# About the solution for "reverse-string" in leetcode

Tags: c++, algorithm

https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseString(string s) {
       // if(s.size() == 0 || s.size() == 1)
       //   return s;
        string::size_type  i = 0;
        string::size_type  j = s.size() - 1;

        while (i < j)
        {
            char temp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        return s;
    }
};
```

But this solution is not passed.
When i uncomment these two lines: `if(s.size() == 0 || s.size() == 1) return s;`, the code pass. i am confused, i think these code are equal.

Comment: If size is 0, what will `i` and `j` be? How does that fit with `while (i < j)`?

Comment: @Raw Leetcode is a website with programming problems. He asks why he has to have that line uncommented to have all tests pass.

Comment: If `size = 0`, `i = 0, j = -1`, the case `while(i < j)` will not execute, the function will `return s`.

Comment: @BoPersson That is exactly the thing: The assumption that 0-1 is less than 0 does not work

Comment: @BlackMamba It will execute, because `j` is huge.

Comment: j<0 is false as size_type is unsigned in your case

Comment: I reckon that if `i=0` than `j=0x7fffffffffffffffLL` rather than `-1`.

Comment: @BlackMamba You could have printed out `i` and `j` with different edge cases.

Comment: You may want to have a lookt at [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) or even better [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: `string::size_type` is `size_t`, which is unsigned, unsigned(0-1) is a huge positive number.

Comment: @Walter: 2's complement representation of -1 is 0xff..., not 0x7f....

Answer (score 5):

When the length is 0 you get out of bounds access (j becomes a large number as it is unsigned).

The length 1 case should be safe to keep commented.